# How to evaluate string as array in Java?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

I have a `String` like this:

```
[["123","Albert","foo"],["456","Mark","bar"],["789","Jackson","baz"]]
```

How can I do to turn it into a corresponding array?

I get this response from a `HttpPost` in `Java` (`Android`).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like json, use a json parser.

Comment: might want to specify if u want one array of 9, or 3 arrays of 3

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis: I got an error: Array cannot be converted in JSONObject
user3126670:
An array as is shown in chain
To list them with loops
123 Albert foo
Mark 456 bar
789 Jackson baz

Comment: The error is pretty descriptive. You're trying to get a json object from a json array. That doesn't make sense. Get a json array instead.

Comment: Suppose that in the table of the database, the columns are:

id, name, nick

try
  {
   String s = "";
   JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
   for (int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
   {
    JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
    s = s +
      "Id: " + json.getString("id")+"\n"+
      "Name: " + json.getString("name")+"\n"+
      "Nick: " + json.getString("nick")+"\n\n";
   }
   
   resultView.setText(s);
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
   Log.e("Log", "Error parsing JSON :("+e.toString());
  }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
JSONArray new_array = new JSONArray(string);
for(int i =0; i < new_array.length(); i++){
     JSONArray arr = new_array.getJSONArray(i);
     for(int j =0; j < arr.length(); j++){
          Log.v("result--",""+arr.getString(j));
     }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it a regular two-dimensional array?

Because I need to manipulate the indices
Or with JSON I can manipulate indexes?

To display something like: 

s=s + "Id :"+arr[0]+"\n"+
"Name :"+arr[1]+"\n"+
"Nick :"+arr[2]+"\n\n";

Comment: Done!
not arr[index]
Is arr.get(index)

:D

Answer (score 3):

Use `GSON`
like:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String[][] myTypes = gson.fromJson(str, String[][].class);
```

search for more example of how to use [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library.

Answer (score 2):

In your format you have to fetch your data for ***JSONArray*** instead of ***JSONObject***.

So you have to use this which make sense

```
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(yourResponsestr);
    for(int i =0; i < jArray .length(); i++){
    JSONArray arr = myarray.getJSONArray(i);
    for(int j =0; j < myarray.length(); j++){
      Log.v("Response Array -->",""+arr.getString(j));
    }
    }
```